# Set svn:externals to current local directory

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

I have the following local folder structure:

```
Top-Level Checkout
|-Project1
|    -Project Specific Files
|
|-Project2
|    -Project Specific Files
```

For which I want to add a svn:externals property to the `Project1` for some .dll files that live in my repository.

I use TortoiseSVN to set the property (if it matters, I don't think it does). I'm attempting to add the svn:externals definition on the `Project1` folder so that my .dll files are downloaded to that folder, forming the following structure

```
Top-Level Checkout
|-Project1
|    -Project Specific Files
|    -.dll1
|    -.dll2
|    -.dll3
|    -.dll4
|
|-Project2
|    -Project Specific Files
```

But the externals property refuses to let me specify that I want to download them to the folder I am currently setting the externals property on.

For example, if my property looks like this:

```
^/Some/Repository/Url "SomeFolder"
```

It will create `SomeFolder` under `Project1` and put the .dlls there.

If I do this

```
^/Some/Repository/Url ""
```

It complains it's invalid. This:

```
^/Some/Repository/Url "\"
```

Will allow me to save it, but then when I try to update and get my externals, it breaks with

> Can't make directory '`Top Level Checkout\Project1\`': The filename,
>   directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

How can I tell it to download the .dlls to the local folder that I'm setting the externals to without it wanting to create a subfolder every time?

Lastly, I haven't tried setting the externals property on `Top-level Checkout`, partially because I think it will still tell me it can't create the directory, but mostly because that is not a viable solution for this project.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: If you don't want to tinker with advanced features of NTFS and want to use only what SVN has to offer then you must either bring the complete directory (which you say you don't want), or each file separately (as per Ben's answer).

Answer (score 2):

IF these DLL files reside in the same repository, you can specify the full name of each file rather than a directory in which to place them. This is called a "file external".

So your rule would look like:

```
^/Some/Repository/URL/file1.dll file1.dll
^/Some/Repository/URL/file2.dll file2.dll
# ...
# etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add comments and stuff to this question.

I read some in depth stuff on the `svn:externals` documentation and found that it *must* create a sub-folder. That's ridiculous limitation to have IMO, but it is what it is.

I ended up putting the external on the top-level folder in this case. It hasn't broken anything to my knowledge, but I also haven't worked on that particular project in a while now. The other devs haven't complained.

Also, I'm leaving this question unanswered because there is no solution to the problem yet.

Comment: That's outdated information, then. You can do externals file-by-file using file externals.

Directory externals must create a subdirectory, because a directory external basically creates a brand new independent working copy. This is also similar to how Subrepositories work in systems like Mercurial and Git.

Comment: I didn't want to specify each file separately. That would require me to make a change to the external every time a new file is added.

Comment: You should be doing that anyway, unless you are ignoring the strong advice from the SVN documentation, telling you to use explicit revision numbers in your externals.